# Updating Counter in App.Config

Tags: c#, config, app-config

I am creating a form-application using C#. This application should create certain files, and these files need to have a incrementing number. Therefor I thought I could store a Counter in app.config and increment it everytime a file is created.

I used wrote this code :

```
System.Configuration.Configuration _Config = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    }

    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lCount;
        if (int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["count"], out lCount))
        {
            _Config.AppSettings.Settings["count"].Value = lCount++.ToString();
            _Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

            MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["count"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Count in Config file is no int");
        }
    }
```

It's not updating the value. Do I need to reload the config or does it not make any sense to store counter value in app.config anyways?

Thanks

Comment: App.config is inappropriate for that. You can use `Settings` or an embedded database like SQLite.

Comment: @Crowcoder better the SQLite approach, in case the app evolves and goes multiuser it could be pretty straightforward to modify.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  `lCount++;` before `toString();`, otherwise the `count` always save the same value, you can try to add [ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection(v=vs.110).aspx) method when you save your new data.

Here is a sample for your question.

```
int i = 0;
Console.WriteLine("i++:" + i++.ToString()); // will get 0

i = 0;
Console.WriteLine("(++i):"+(++i).ToString()); // will get 1
```

[c# online sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2HHErg)

or you can use `(++lCount).ToString()` instead of `lCount++.ToString()`

```
 _Config.AppSettings.Settings["count"].Value = (++lCount).ToString();
```

the code looks like this.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration _Config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
int lCount;
if (int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["count"], out lCount))
{
     lCount++;
    _Config.AppSettings.Settings["count"].Value = lCount.ToString();
    _Config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(_Config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
}
```

**Note:**

I will suggest you save the counter in `DB` instead of `App.config`.